# Help with listing current users submitted custom post type in template file

Tags: posts, customization

I have the following code to list the member's post that they created. However it is listing all posts. Anyone know how to fix it? Thank you!

```
    <?php

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
  $args=array(
    'member' => $current_user->ID,
    'post_type' => 'listing',
    'post_status' => 'publish, private',
    'posts_per_page' => '10'
  );
  $my_query = null;
  $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
  if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo 'Your Posts';
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
      <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
      <?php
    endwhile;
  }
  wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `member` argument for [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters), you want to pass the user ID as `author`.